# How to stop fluid simulation to stick with moving obstacle after collision

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have this little guy here jumping into a pond.

[image]

However, the fluid simulation is causing a weird bubble-like wrap around him as he swims in the water.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could try experimenting with the "remove air bubbles" option in the domain settings.

Comment: It worked! Thank you :D I don't know how to put your comment as the answer so I'll drop in my own answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nick Bosse 18,
So the solution is to check 'remove air bubbles' in Physics -> Fluid -> Fluid Boundary.
*Note: After I did this, the effect of the frog leaping into the water doesn't look as 'strong' as before but I have bubbles emitting from it. So I keyframed the size of the bubbles from big ones when it enters the water, to smaller ones when it's swimming.